# Simple JavaFX Browser Only Works The First Time Its Opened

Tags: java, javafx

I have this code to open a custom Java browser:

```
private void openNavigator(){

    Navigator browser = new Navigator();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

        browser.initComponents();

        browser.setVisible(true);

        browser.loadURL("http://XXXXXXXX:8888/YYYYYY/ZZZZ");
    });
}
```

In the other hand i have the code of the navigator:

```
public class Navigator extends JFrame {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Navegador.class.getName());
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1951385676682823399L;

    private WebView view;
    private JFXPanel javaFxPanel;
    private WebEngine engine;

    private JLabel labelStatus;
    private JTextField direction;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    private java.net.CookieManager cookiesManager;


    public void initComponents() {

        if (cookiesManager != null) {
            cookiesManager = new java.net.CookieManager();
            java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(cookiesManager);
        }

        javaFxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        labelStatus = new JLabel();

        JPanel panelTodo = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JButton botonBuscar = new JButton("Search");
        direction = new JTextField();
        progressBar = new JProgressBar();

        createScene();

        ActionListener direcctionListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loadURL(direction.getText());
            }
        };

        botonBuscar.addActionListener(direcctionListener);
        direction.addActionListener(direcctionListener);

        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 18));
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        JPanel topBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        topBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        topBar.add(direction, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        topBar.add(botonBuscar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanel statusBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        statusBar.add(labelStatus, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        statusBar.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        panelTodo.add(topBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelTodo.add(javaFxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelTodo.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        getContentPane().add(panelTodo);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    private void createScene() {

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            view = new WebView();
            engine = view.getEngine();

            engine.setOnAlert((WebEvent<String> wEvent) -> {
                System.out.println("JS alert() message: " + wEvent.getData());
            });

            engine.titleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Navegador.this.setTitle(newValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            engine.setOnStatusChanged(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(final WebEvent<String> event) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            labelStatus.setText(event.getData());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            engine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String viejoValor, final String nuevoValor) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            direction.setText(nuevoValor);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            engine.getLoadWorker().workDoneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, final Number newValue) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setValue(newValue.intValue());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            engine.getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty()
                    .addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {

                        @Override
                        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> o, Throwable old, final Throwable value) {
                            if (engine.getLoadWorker().getState() == FAILED) {
                                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        //TODO Handling Exception
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });

            javaFxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
        });
    }

    public void loadURL(String url) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String urlTemporal = toURL(url);

                if (urlTemporal == null) {
                    urlTemporal = toURL("http://" + url);
                }

                engine.load(urlTemporal);
            }
        });
    }

    private static String toURL(String str) {
        try {
            return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is that when i open the navigator for the first time it works , but when i close it and then open again it only shows the `TextField` and the `Button`

Notes:

1. I use a javaswing button to open the navigator whit the
   `openNavigator()` method
2. When i left one Navigator without closing and at the same time i
   open one or more Navigators it works perfectly

First time I open the Navigator:

[image]

Second time I open the Navigator:

[image]

Comment: Why are you mixing Swing and JavaFX? Where is the JavaFX stage? I'm guessing the primary stage is closed and so the JavaFX toolkit gets finalized/destroyed, but it's hard to tell without the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: It is not entirely clear from the `JFXPanel` documentation, but I'm guessing maybe it initializes the JavaFX toolkit without needing an `Application` class or a primary stage. In this case, it may be enough to call `Platform.setImplicitExit(false)` so that the JavaFX thread doesn't terminate prematurely.

Comment: @sillyfly Thanks you soo much Platform.setImplicitExit(false) works perfectly, answer back this question to give you the acepted answer, really thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaFX thread/toolkit must be running. Apparently, creating a `JFXPanel` is enough to initialize it, but once it is closed the thread is terminated automatically.
To stop it from automatically closing call

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
```

so the JavaFX toolkit only closes when the `Platform#exit` method is called, or the entire application terminates.